# Keep Labels and text input fields on one line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, text, input, label

Can some explain to me why this is not working... I just want the input boxes to be on the same line as the labels.  I cannot see what I am missing here.

```
<section id="student-info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h4 class="section_title">Student Information</h4></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="name" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">John Doe</div>
        <div id="email" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">jdoe@nowhere.com</div>
        <div id="colgateid" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">ID: 123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="dg-leave" class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <label for="SG-Leave" class="control-label">SG/Leave: </label>
          <input class="form-control"  name="SG-Leave" type="text" tabindex="1" id="SG-Leave" placeholder="SG/Leave"></div>
        <div id="reg-id" class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <label for="reg-id" class="control-label">Registration ID: </label>
           <input size="10" class="form-control"  name="reg-id" type="text" tabindex="1" id="reg-id" placeholder="Reg ID"></div>
        <div id="classyear" class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Class of: 2016</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pkhr3wys/5/